# using async pipe with angular2 not working

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Whenever i use the async pipe i am getting console errors.

```
   <component *ngFor="#c of columns | async" [column]="c"></component>
```

I get this console error:

> EXCEPTION: Invalid argument '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' in [columns | async in Projects@1:51]
>   browser_adapter.js:76 EXCEPTION: Invalid argument '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' in [columns | async in Projects@1:51]

Is there something missing?

Comment: Can you please add the code of `column`?

Answer (score 4):

The `columns` attribute must be either an observable or a promise (not an array or something else. See this line in the source code of Angular2 (`AsyncPipe` class): https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L109.

In the case of an HTTP call for example, you need to set the `columns` attribute with the returned observable directly. The `async` will be responsible to handle it, i.e. calling its `subscribe` method, dispose it. Here is a sample:

```
this.columns = 
   this.http.get('https://angular2.apispark.net/v1/companies/', {
     headers: headers
   }).map(res => res.json());
```

Instead of setting the `columns attribute from a subscribe method you manage by yourself:

```
this.http.get('https://angular2.apispark.net/v1/companies/', {
  headers: headers
})
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(data => this.columns = data);
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry